# Comparing to string with each other in Java

Tags: java

I'm looking for a solution to compare two strings with each other. I have already found a few suggestions but i'm not really understanding how to do it. I want to do something like that:

```
String a = 23;
String b = 2;

if (a < b)
System.out.println("...");
else ..
```

I've found the compareTo method but i don't get the idea behind it. The code would be something like:

```
String a = 23;
String b = 2;

if (a.compareTo(b) < 0)
System.out.println("...");
else ..
```

But why should i compare to strings with each other and then compare it to zero?? I'm really confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read the API for [compareTo](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String))

```
a.compareTo(b)
```

The result of this method call:
is a negative number (hence < 0) if a precedes b alphabetically (e.g. a="apple", b="bananna")
is 0 if it is the same string 
and is a positive number if a is after b alphabetically

If you want to compare numeric values, either do your comparison on Integers or first parse the strings e.g.

```
if (Integer.parseInt(a) < Integer.parseInt(b)){
   ...
} else {
 ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there no way to do my comparison of numerical values with the compareTo ?

Comment: Integer implement Comparable so you can do aInteger.compareTo(bInteger) where aInteger and bInteger are instance of Integer class.

Comment: Not if your a and b are of type String.

Comment: I further clarified the Integer comparison in the example there... That will do a numeric comparison on integer Strings for you.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot do `a < b` in java with `String`. You have to use [compareTo](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29) or [Comparator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).
You cannot write `String a = 23;` also. You can convert them to integer and then do `a < b`.

Comment: Yes, i know. I just wanted to show what i want to do. I'm not understanding how to use "compareTo" to compare two numbers which each other.

Comment: You can't compare numbers that way.  If `b` had been `3` instead of `2` then `a.compareTo(b)` would return true because `23` is _lexicographically_ less than `3`.

Answer (score 1):

Comparing `a` and `b` directly just compares their internal *references*.

Note (as Jon pointed out) that you can't even use the `<` operators on Strings, although you *can* use the `==` operator.

However to compare their *contents* use you must use the `equals()` or `comparesTo()` methods.

To demostrate the `==` issues:

```
public class foobar {
    static public void main(String[] args) {

        // two identical strings
        String a = "foo";
        String b = "foo";

        // and the result of comparing them
        System.out.println(" ==              returns " + (a == b));
        System.out.println(" String.equals() returns " + a.equals(b));

        // append the same string on the end of each
        a += "bar";
        b += "bar";

        // and compare them again
        System.out.println(" ==              returns " + (a == b));
        System.out.println(" String.equals() returns " + a.equals(b));
    }
}

% java foobar
 ==              returns true
 String.equals() returns true
 ==              returns false
 String.equals() returns true
```

When `a` and `b` are both initialised from the same string then `string interning` initialises both references to look at that immutable string.  This means that *initially* `a == b` is true.

However as soon as you modify them, even if the contents end up the same, the `==` test fails.

Comment: You simply *can't* compare `a` and `b` with `<` - it doesn't compare internal references, it doesn't compile!

Comment: @Jon Skeet, good point, I should have tested that first.  Answer updated with stuff about (mis)use of `==`.

Answer (score 1):

Do like this, it will give the correct result

```
  String s = "22";
        string s1 = "2";
        string output = "";
        if (s.CompareTo(s1) > 0)
            output = "S is grater";
        else
            output = "s is smaller";
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need compare numbers you need override compare() method, because java not allow to override operators.
You can use something like this:

```
public class TestString implements Comparator<String> {
    private static TestString ts = new TestString();
    static public int compareStrings(String s1, String s2) {
        return ts.compare(s1, s2);
    }

    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        Integer i1 = Integer.parseInt(s1);
        Integer i2 = Integer.parseInt(s2);
        if (i1 == i2) {
            return 0;
        } else if (i1 < i2) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    static public void main(String[] args) {
        String s1 = "10";
        String s2 = "3";
        if (TestString.compareStrings(s1, s2) < 0) {
            System.out.println("<");
        } else if (TestString.compareStrings(s1, s2) > 0) {
            System.out.println(">");
        }
    }
}
```

But if you need actually compare values (not for ordering) you look at program design, maybe there need some changes.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use String if you want to use the larger than, smaller than operators. Use int then if you want to change it to string later useInteger.toString(a)